# How to prove differetiability in $\Bbb K^2$?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have to investigate differentiability in all points of the following function:
$$f: \Bbb {R}^2 \to \Bbb R \: \: \: \: \: \: \: f(x,y):=\begin{cases} y-x &\mbox{if } y\ge x^2 \\
0 & \mbox{if } y\lt x^2 \end{cases}$$

I know this is an elementary question but i don't understand how to solve it, and onine there are only very specific examples. I know that for differentiability at point $\xi$ there has to be a linear Map $L$ such that: $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(\xi +h) -f(\xi ) - L(h)}{||h||_2}=0$$
or alternatively i have to find a linear map $L$ and a map $r$ such that $$f(\xi + h ) - f(\xi ) = L(h) + r(h) \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\mathrm{ AND } \:\:\:\:\:\:\: \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {r(h)}{||h||_2}=0$$
but i don't know how to generally really formally do the prove. Can someone give me some pointers on how to do this? (I've read that one has to use the partial derivatives but i don't know where they come to play, and also how to handle the $h$ or find the $L$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In English, the word "I" is always written as a capital letter. So one writes: "but I don't know" and **not** "but i don't know".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is differentiable, its partial derivative exists. The restriction of $f$ on
 $y>x^2$ or $y<x^2$ is a polynomial, so it is differentiable on these domains.

Let $(x,y)$ such that $y=x^2$ $lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}{\partial\over {\partial x}}f(x-h,y)=-1$ and $lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+}{\partial\over {\partial x}}f(x+h,y)=0$ thus $f$ is not differentiable at $(x,x^2)$.

Comment: Ah ok, perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$f$ is differentiable if all partials are continuous. Furthermore, if it exists, the total differential is given by $\nabla f$.